# Do not overlap text in flags

Tags: highcharts

How can I fix it so the letter inside the flag does not overlap onto other flags?

[image: flags]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @joelcloud, I've tried to reproduce the problem here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fuwk3907/ but everything seems to work as expected. Could you adapt the example to show the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It will fix by adding

```
labels: {
        allowOverlap: false
    }
```

Comment: Check this example
https://jsfiddle.net/q8x9u03o/